# motorcycle oil for m50B25TU (BMW E34)?

Tags: engine, oil, bmw

I just bought an e34 from a friend and he said he uses [liqui moly racing synth 10w-50](http://www.liqui-moly.de/liquimoly/produktdb.nsf/id/en_1502.html?Opendocument&land=GB&voilalang=e&voiladb=web.nsf) for the engine.

My mechanic was quite surprised when I told him and said I shouldn't use that, instead use real car engine oil. Still my friend is also a mechanic with years of experience on BMWs...
I've read a lot about the topic and haven't seen any consensus about whether it is ok or not.

Areas of application from the description is:

> Specially developed for all-season use in street, off-road and racing
>   machines as well as ATVs, scooters and snowmobiles operated under
>   normal to extreme conditions. Exceptionally well-suited for use with
>   or without a wet clutch

So should I stick with it or switch to something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go with the recommended oil. The manufacturer should know much more about the vehicle they designed than your mechanic friend. Here are the factory recommendations for the `E34`. This covers all engine options that were available for the `E34` chassis.

***Viscosity :***

- *Cold climate:* 5W-30
- *Mild climate:* 10W-30
- *Warm or hot climate:* 15W-50